# Check if a key has been pressed on rust? using just std library?

Tags: rust

I am trying to develop a rather simple program on rust, I want to be able to detect keydown presses from the keyboard, this will be used to control a drone using "WASD" just like a game.

The thing is, I have tried to check if there is any way to do it by using just the std library, but every answer I see is something like "use termion" or "use this".

Is there a way to do it just with the std library from rust? without using external crates.

Ty!

So far I have tried to develop a terminal-like program that sends commands, I want to improve it by reading the keys rather than having to send the commands to the drone one by one. Reading these commands directly from what I press would be rather useful. (Also, this is done using UDP, in case that matters)

Comment: All of those other libraries you mention are calling OS-level functions (things written in C or lower-level). `std` can't do this. You probably could make those OS calls directly, but it would be much more tedious than pulling in a dependency designed for it

Comment: Oh, I see~ so these crates were done using C? I am a bit curious, since I am still learning (rookie here) I wanted to create it myself.

Comment: @Blanks no, what it means is that reading keyboard input is a tedious, low-level operation that is highly target-dependent. It can be written in Rust (in fact, termion is written entirely in Rust). The point is that it's far from being a simple task, to which there is a short and to-the-point solution, besides using a library. If you want to see more details about how it is done, I would suggest reading [termion's sources](https://gitlab.redox-os.org/redox-os/termion).

Comment: @BlackBeans thank you for the explanation, I have decided to do it myself just for the sake of learning the hard way. Now that I know is possible, then I will try it, I guess I will have to somehow find how to avoid blocking the stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this depends on the target OS and terminal.

On Unix systems, this is done by switching stdin/stdout to raw mode and using [ANSI control sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (but note that there are several sets of control sequences and the right one to use depends on your terminal application, e.g. the Linux console uses different sequences from xterm and Gnome Terminal uses yet another set).

On Windows, this requires calling system functions from [the Windows Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference).

The existing crates abstract all those differences into a single unified cross-platform API.

Comment: Cheers for that background info. It seems like something I needed to hear. I will be using purely Unix for testing purposes (Linux to be more specific).